# Add Footer only to last page of the word document using open XML sdk with C#

Tags: c#, sdk, openxml

I am new to OPEN XML SDK 2.5 using C#. I created a doc with a table in it and the contents in the table may go more than 500 rows. So the document may have multiple pages. I have added header and footer successfully. But What I want is that I need to add footer only to the last page in the document. How to do this. Please find attached the sample code. Hope my question is clear

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @'C:\temp\HeaderFooterDocument.docx';
            CreateTable(fileName);
        }

        public static void ApplyHeader(WordprocessingDocument doc)
        {
            // Get the main document part.
            MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

            HeaderPart headerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>('r97');



            Header header1 = new Header();

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { };



            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = 'Header stuff';

            run1.Append(text1);

            Text text3 = new Text();
            text3.Text = '\rHeader stuff';

            run1.Append(text3);

            paragraph1.Append(run1);


            header1.Append(paragraph1);

            headerPart1.Header = header1;



            SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (sectionProperties1 == null)
            {
                sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
                mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
            }
            HeaderReference headerReference1 = new HeaderReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = 'r97' };


            sectionProperties1.InsertAt(headerReference1, 0);

        }
        public static void ApplyFooter(WordprocessingDocument doc)
        {
            // Get the main document part.
            MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

            FooterPart footerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>('r98');



            Footer footer1 = new Footer();

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { };



            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = 'Footer stuff';

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(run1);


            footer1.Append(paragraph1);

            footerPart1.Footer = footer1;



            SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (sectionProperties1 == null)
            {
                sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
                mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
            }
            FooterReference footerReference1 = new FooterReference() { Type = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = 'r98' };


            sectionProperties1.InsertAt(footerReference1, 0);

        }
        // Insert a table into a word processing document.
        public static void CreateTable(string fileName)
        {
            // Use the file name and path passed in as an argument 
            // to open an existing Word 2007 document.

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Create(fileName, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {

                // Add a main document part. 
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the document structure and add some text.
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
                Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                run.AppendChild(new Text('Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument'));
                ApplyHeader(wordDocument);

                ApplyFooter(wordDocument);
                // Create an empty table.
                Table table = new Table();

                // Create a TableProperties object and specify its border information.
                TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
                    new TableBorders(
                        new TopBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new BottomBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new LeftBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new RightBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new InsideHorizontalBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        },
                        new InsideVerticalBorder()
                        {
                            Val =
                            new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.None),
                            Size = 24
                        }
                    )
                );

                // Append the TableProperties object to the empty table.
                table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);

                // Create a row.
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                // Create a cell.
                TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();

                // Specify the width property of the table cell.
                tc1.Append(new TableCellProperties(
                    new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = '2400' }));

                // Specify the table cell content.
                tc1.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text('some text'))));

                // Append the table cell to the table row.
                tr.Append(tc1);

                // Create a second table cell by copying the OuterXml value of the first table cell.
                TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(tc1.OuterXml);

                // Append the table cell to the table row.
                tr.Append(tc2);

                // Append the table row to the table.
                table.Append(tr);

                for (int rows = 1; rows < 50; rows++)
                {
                    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
                    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < 2; index2++)
                    {
                        TableCell newCells = new TableCell();
                        newCells.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text('row' + rows + 'column' + index2))));
                        tr2.Append(newCells);
                    }
                    table.Append(tr2);
                    // Append the table to the document.

                }
                wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers and footers are linked to SECTIONS in Word. The Headers and Footers can vary according to section. And the types of header and footer are: first page, odd pages (default) and even pages when the corresponding properties are activated. By default, there's only the odd page type and it will "cascade" throughout the document if there is no other instruction.

There is no option for a "last page" header or footer. But it can be faked using a set of nested fields code that tests whether the page number of the current page is equivalent to the total number of pages in the document. If it is, then the header or footer is displayed, otherwise nothing. The field code looks like this:

```
{ IF { PAGE } = {NUMPAGESS } "Text to appear" "" }
```

Note that the field brackets { } MUST be inserted using Ctrl+F9, they cannot be typed from the keyboard any other way. Use Alt+F9 to toggle between field code and field result displays.

Create a small sample document with this field code, then view it in the Open XML SDK to see the XML it generates AND the code used to create it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.I did that and it worked.